# Why is the National Mall open for an immigration rally?

Tags: united-states, government-shutdown

The [Washington Examiner had this article](http://m.washingtonexaminer.com/park-service-oks-immigration-reform-rally-on-closed-national-mall/article/2536908)

> A planned immigration reform rally will take place on the National Mall on Tuesday even though the site is closed due to the government shutdown.
>
> Organizers for the "Camino Americano: March for Immigration Reform" were spotted Monday setting up a stage and equipment on the National Mall for the rally which will take place on Tuesday.
>
> A few scattered barriers around the park have signs informing visitors that the area is closed as a result of the government shutdown.

**Is there some exemption for a government shutdown for immigration reform rallies?**

**Why did the National Park Service close all national parks, except for this rally?**

Comment: Isn't the answer in your own quote?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is their some exemption for a government shutdown for immigration reform rallies?

No.

> Why did the National Park Service close all national parks, except for this rally?

They didn't.

Some Tea Party republicans used the closing of the WWII memorial as a political talking point and eventually got the Parks Service to [open it under '1st Amendment Grounds'](http://www.buzzfeed.com/evanmcsan/obama-administration-reopens-monuments-for-first-amendment-a) which, as you see in the article, is the explanation as to why the rally is also happening.

> Susana Flores, a spokesperson for the rally, confirmed for the Washington Examiner that the Park Service will allow the event to take place **under the group's rights granted by the First Amendment.**